# Inet6 address insteaf of inet Android repackagingLab

Tags: android, inet, software-packaging

Hello guys so im trying to do an Android RepackagingLab for my Uni but the Android 7.1 VMs is giving me a inet6 address instead of an inet. The goal is to connect from my other vm and install a "malicious" app on the android. Any help to switch the IP to normal? [image]

[image]